# remove Qty option from product add to cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Remove this Qty option from cart page[image: Bookstore]

Comment: Can please let me know how to do?

Comment: enable template hint and check from which file the content is loading

Comment: template hint? i dint get you

Answer (score 1):

Go to **`app/design/frontend/<theme-package>/<theme>/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`** and find and either comment out or remove below code:

```
<td class="a-center">
    <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
           data-cart-item-id="<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($_item->getSku()) ?>"
           value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

And if file not exist to copy from app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

and comment below code

```
<td class="product-cart-actions" data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('Qty'); ?>">
        <input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4"
               data-cart-item-id="<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($_item->getSku()) ?>"
               title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" />

        <button type="submit" name="update_cart_action" data-cart-item-update value="update_qty" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Update')); ?>" class="button btn-update"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update'); ?></span></span>
        </button>

        <ul class="cart-links">
            <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getConfigureUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Edit item parameters')) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
            <li>
                <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getMoveFromCartUrl($_item->getId()); ?>" class="link-wishlist use-ajax"><?php echo $this->__('Move to wishlist'); ?></a>
                <?php endif ?>
            </li>
            <?php endif ?>
        </ul>

</td>
```

Also you need to remove header of quantity

For that go to app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/checkout/cart.phtml

if not file available in theme copy from app/design/frontend/base/defualt/template/checkout/cart.phtml

and comment below code :

```
<th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center">
                        <?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>

                        <?php /*if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
                            <span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Move to Wishlist') ?></span>
                        <?php endif*/ ?>

                    </th>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the inconvenience

please go to this url
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\downloadable\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml

and comment below code

```
<td class="a-center">
    <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4"
           title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12"/>
</td>
```